# Vlookup to lookup in two columns simultaneously

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet having data as follows:

```
 JobName    Source Total Records    Target Total Records    Rejected Records Count               Run Day     Status
    Job1                    2222                    2200                       22    03/07/2015 00:31:02     JOB_ENDED_WITH_REJECTS
    Job1.1                  2200                    2000                      200    03/07/2015 00:31:02     JOB_ENDED_WITH_REJECTS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    Job1                    1111                    1100                       11    03/08/2015 00:31:02     JOB_ENDED_WITH_REJECTS
    Job1.1                  1100                    1000                      100    03/08/2015 00:31:02     JOB_ENDED_WITH_REJECTS
```

I need to show the details in Sheet2 as follows:

```
    Main Job                Job1
    Sub Job                 Job1.1
    Run Day                 03/07/2015 00:31:02
    Total Rejected Records  222
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Main Job                Job1
    Sub Job                 Job1.1
    Run Day                 03/08/2015 00:31:02
    Total Rejected Records  111
```

The values for Main Job and Run Day are entered manually in the sheet2. As I enter this, I need to have a lookup for the sheet1 data that matches the jobname and date and to calculate the total rejected rows.

> Eg.Job1.1 is a sub job of Job1 and hence Total Rejected rows is the
>   sum of rejected rows for the two.

Is there any method in Vlookup function that can be used to lookup in two columns simultaneously, so that I can lookup for the jobname and date at the same time?

I need to implement in Excel VBA.

Comment: So you manually enter the date and time down to the second and it will always match exactly to the job and subjob's *Run Day*? How does the subjob get entered? Seems you  want a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5), not a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).

Comment: @jeeped :Values for Main Job,Sub Job and Run Day are entered manually

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your best bet here is with 2 SUMIFS functions, in the Total Rejected rows in the second sheet.

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1A:A,Sheet2!B1,Sheet1E:E,Sheet2!B3)+SUMIFS(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1A:A,Sheet2!B2,Sheet1E:E,Sheet2!B3)
```

This will do a sum on the rejected records from Sheet1 twice (once for each MainJob and SubJob) with the condition that it also fits the date.

Alternatively you can also add a new column to sheet 1 where you mention only the main job and then do only one SUMIFS with two conditions, one for matching the MainJob the other for matching the date.

Comment: If you add a wildcard (e.g. *) to the job, it should pick up the subjob. Example: `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!D:D, Sheet1!A:A, B1&"*", Sheet1!E:E, B3)`